# Error While Connecting Pentaho Kette with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho-spoon

Error connecting to database [test] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.

```
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:83)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestResults(DatabaseFactory.java:112)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnectionSuccess(DatabaseMeta.java:2811)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.test(DatabaseDialog.java:110)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.test(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:157)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2$3.widgetSelected(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:147)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizard.createAndRunDatabaseWizard(CreateDatabaseWizard.java:131)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createDatabaseWizard(Spoon.java:7572)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1381)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7817)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9179)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:707)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.

```
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:583)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
... 46 more
```

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:614)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:194)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:567)
... 47 more

Hostname: localhost
Port: 5432
Database name: test

Answer (score 0):

Your password verifier is stored on the server in the "scram-sha-256" format, but your driver is too old to support that format.  Upgrade the JDBC driver.  Or less prefered, change `password_encryption` on the server to "md5" and then reset the password.